# Memory Overhead of Android Binders

Tags: android, performance, ipc

While I am somewhat familiar with the process Binders use to communicate across processes, I was wondering if the fact that they have to interact with the Binder Driver on kernel significantly increased the memory overhead of creating the object.

Furthermore, does creating a significant number of Binders limit the transaction speed of existing Binders even if the number of transactions doesn't increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to dig into the libbinder code as well as the kernel driver code to really do an analysis of memory consumption.  However, the overhead is likely not very much as internally the binder driver has its driver object then links to the actual binders owned by the calling process.  It also limits the number of threads which can be used by calling processes to handle simultaneous transactions.

As far as performance goes, the main limiting factor is going to be the size of the transaction data through a given binder.  Each binder gets a fixed size buffer (1MB) to handle *all transactions* for that binder.  So if there are multiple transactions going on simultaneously for a specific binder, the total data used by all of them is what counts against this limit.  This can be very tricky to troubleshoot or handle gracefully as the exception which occurs (Java level) does not indicate if it was the *send* part of the transaction or the *receive* part.  The rule of thumb is that data moving across a binder needs to be small, like message passing.  It's not well suited for something like streaming data.  Android uses the *ashmem* driver support to better handle this as well as the ability to share file descriptors across binders.

The binders themselves are tracked in a btree, so lookup should be extremely fast.  It would be interesting to have some stats on this for a given process as well as if the total number of binders in the system gets to a high level, but I'm not aware of any such data.